# How to have an app centered on and/or fill the screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to Xcode and I have a very simple layout with a square ImageView with two buttons below it. I wrap these in a UIView called Box (as a subview target for `viewForZoomingInScrollView`), which is wrapped in a ScrollView.

I tried building it in two different ways with the SingleView template. In the first way I changed the ViewController's view to a ScrollView, like this.

[image]

Second, I also tried it with the Scrollview inside the ViewController's view like this.

[image]

Everything works fine or as expected, in both cases, except: In both cases, the entire ViewController, stays pinned to the top left corner of the screen, regardless of orientation or zoom level.

*** Omg, I solved all my resource management and action issues in one day and now I have spent nearly a week fighting with Layout ***

When I have no constraints, like this:

[image]

The App opens like this. View is Black, ScrollView is purple, Box is DKGray, and ImageView is LTGray

[image: View is Black, ScrollView is Purple, Box is DKGray, and ImageView is LTGray]

When I pinch it, the image stays (after bouncing) pinned to the top left.

[image]

If I add centering constraints to ScrollView and Box,

[image]

ScrollView's constraints are respected but Box's are not. (Actually when the app opens Box fills ScrollView, it is only after pinching that Box goes up into the top left. Can scrolling destroy the constraints...? Do I have to put constraints in `scrollViewDidEndZooming`?)

[image]

Here are my current sub-questions. When Layout doesn't have enough constraints, it must add them. Does the constraints it adds have priority over mine? Is there a way to see what constraints it adds? I get these warnings with the constraints above.

[image]

Over Arching Question: **How do I get it to be in the center of the iOS screen, or to fill the screen?** I imagine there is an Interface Builder solution and a code solution, either or both would be of interest.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: what constraints have you added ?

Comment: Isn't it great that questions can be down voted without explanation? That really encourages use of Stackoverflow.

Comment: For some reason in the first situation, no constraints were required. In the second, it complained so I added the "suggested constraints". The image view is pinned to the top, right, and left of the Box and the buttons are pinned to the image view on the top and bottom of the Box on the bottom.

Comment: To make something go to center of the view, use two constraints. "Align Center X to superview" and "Align center Y to superview". If you want it to fill the view as well, Add two more constants to those two. Those are "Equal width to super view" and "Equal height to superview"

Comment: Just drag a line from your subview to superview and you will see an option to add all of these traits.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have tried adding constraints all different ways to ScrollView and Box but I don't seem to be getting up high enough in the hierarchy. They just view to be affecting what happens within a rectangle pinned to the top left, not positioning that rectangle on the screen.

Comment: It seems like I should be adding constraints to View but it doesn't seem to allow that.

Comment: Constraints shown on the image above looks legit. However the image view also needs constraints (center X and Y will be enough for validation, but probably in your case should be pinned to box bounds).

Comment: Thanks Aleksander. When I try pinning ImageView, all hell breaks loose. I will try to post something comprehensible.

Answer (score 2):

**Changing the element alignment**

Each element needs to have constraints to outline where it should display in it's parent. i.e. right now you have an image, inside a view, inside a scroll view. So each of those three elements needs to have constraints set.

For each element:

1. Click the element
2. Click the 'Add new alignment contraints' button at the bottom right
3. Check the 'Horizontally in container' and 'Vertically in container' checkbox and then click the 'Add 2 constraints' button

Run your app and you should now see that the image is centre aligned, both horizontally and vertically.

**Changing the element size dynamically**
This is also easy to do through the storyboards. This video shows you how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSsR1NlQvMA
The only extra thing is that you'll need to do this with each element, as per above.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have added more of the stuff I have tried above. When I add centering constraints, ScrollView is centered but Box is not.

Comment: I would like to set Box to be nearly 100% of the smaller screen size dimension. Do I have to do that in code?

Comment: Okay - I would delete all of the constraints from the box element and try again. Sometimes they conflict. Also check your issue navigator - up the top left where you navigate through the project files, you'll notice a folder icon selected. Three across from that is a warning icon. Do any of the warnings here refer to the 'box' element? I'll update my original comment to include how to change the element size.

Answer (score 1):

Try to select your scrollView and in Pin menu of autoLyout try to add these constraints.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have tried adding constraints, like these and all different ways to ScrollView and Box but I don't seem to be getting up high enough in the hierarchy. They just view to be affecting what happens within a rectangle pinned to the top left, not positioning that rectangle on the screen.

Comment: share your project may be we can help

Comment: How do I share it?

Comment: dropbox link may be?

Comment: Oh I thought stackoverflow might have some facility. I don't have dropbox currently. I'll think about whether I have a way to share it.